# Using a png instead of aspx code

Tags: asp.net

When I put this code in

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" style="top: 170px; left: 890px;
 position: absolute;" Font-Names="verdana" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="13px" />
```

it displays a logout object on my webpage that is underlined and when I click it it obviously logs me out.

Is it at all possible to use a use a .png image that I have created that when clicked would do the same job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LoginImageUrl` and `LogoutImageUrl` attributes

For example...

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LoginImageUrl="~/login.png" LogoutImageUrl="~/logout.png" ... />
```

Comment: @Ross You're welcome :-)  To be honest, I didn't even know of the existence of the control, all I did was create an instance of it (after reading your question) and had a look through the methods and parameters!

Answer (score 0):

You could add an ImageButton to your page and have the click handler call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut`.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```